# Unit testing exception handling for third party exceptions with internal constructors

Tags: .net, unit-testing

We use a third party library to communicate with their server software, which we can’t modify.  Calls to the library can fail, by throwing exceptions similar to the following:

```
class LibraryException : Exception {
    internal LibraryException() {};
    string ExceptionDetails {public get; internal set; }
}
```

Depending on the contents of ‘ExceptionDetails’, our calling code has to perform different actions (some errors are fatal, others are not), and I would like to test this code.  The problem I have is that because ‘LibraryException’ has an internal constructor, I can’t find a way of creating one.  I’ve tried new’ing one up, deriving a child class and using Activator.CreateInstance.  Is there any way of working around this?

I’ve thought about changing the build, so that for a subset of tests it would link in a different binary, but this seems like it would be a maintenance nightmare, so at the moment the area is only covered by integration tests.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it should work with `Activator.CreateInstance` when using the overload that accepts `BindingFlags`:

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(LibraryException),
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
    null,
    null,
    null);
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out I had two problems, I was missing one of the BindingFlags (Instance) and I was assuming that the exception had a default constructor, since it didn't show up in the object browser.  Reflecting the constructor on the exception showed that it's missing extra parameters which have allowed me to construct it.