# How to mock events with internal constructors

Tags: c#, events, testing, moq, exchangewebservices

I have a service responsible for subscribing to EWS for new mail notification. I've created an interface for the service in order to mock it and test a dummy implementation. However, I'm running into a wall whenever I try to manually tell what my events are supposed to do.

Here is my concrete implementation.

```
public interface IExchangeService
{
    void Subscribe();
}

public class ExchangeServiceSubscriber : IExchangeService
{
    private readonly ExchangeService _exchangeService;
    private readonly IConsumer<IEmail> _consumer;

    public ExchangeServiceSubscriber(
        ExchangeService exchangeService, 
        IConsumer<IEmail> consumer)
    {
        _exchangeService = exchangeService;
        _consumer = consumer;
    }

    public void Subscribe()
    {
        // code to subscribe

        streamingConnection.OnNotificationEvent += OnEvent;

        streamingConnection.Open();
    }

    public void OnEvent(object sender, NotificationEventArgs args)
    {
        foreach (NotificationEvent triggeredEvent in args.Events)
        {
            if (triggeredEvent is ItemEvent)
            {
                var propertySet = new PropertySet(ItemSchema.UniqueBody, ItemSchema.Attachments)
                {
                    RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text
                };
                EmailMessage email = EmailMessage.Bind(args.Subscription.Service,
                                                       ((ItemEvent)triggeredEvent).ItemId, propertySet);

                _consumer.Consume(new ExchangeEmail { Body = email.UniqueBody });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And unfortunatly, almost every class in EWS is either sealed or has an internal constructor which really limits how I decouple them, it seems. I've attempted to set the expectation for `NotificationEventArgs` (for example) but it uses an internal constructor.

Here is some ideas I've been fiddling with. You can read about mocking events [here](http://code.google.com/p/moq/wiki/QuickStart#Events).

`mock.Setup(x => x.OnEvent(new object(), new NotificationEventArgs()));`
Issue with that is `NotificationEventArgs` uses an internal constructor.

I could see getting this working with some sort of wrapper but I'm not exactly sure what it would look like. One of the big problems is the way EWS is made pretty much prevents anyone from manually injecting dependencies. I'm essentially trying to test that whenever event `OnEvent` fires that the email will actually get consumed. Also, while I would like to test this functionality I'm not sure it's worth fighting EWS every step of the way.

Comment: Do you mean `internal` when you write `inline`? Where is `SubscriptionErrorEventArgs` used in your code sample?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. I did mean `internal`. And I meant to write `NotificationEventArgs` instead of `SubscriptionErrorEventArgs`. See edit.

Comment: Could you please show your current approach that is not working? Reason: I don't know MOQ, but your approach might still enable me to come up with some ideas.

Comment: See edit. I've also added the Moq documentation in regards to mocking events.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, see answer for a suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's first see, what you can't do:

- You can't subclass `NotificationEventArgs` because the ctor is internal.
- You can't create an instance directly for the same reason.

So basically, you can't create an instance of this class using the "normal way". I assume you already checked for a factory method or class?

This leaves us with only one option: Instantiate the class using reflection, e.g. with the help of the `Activator.CreateInstance` method: [Unit testing exception handling for third party exceptions with internal constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498162/unit-testing-exception-handling-for-third-party-exceptions-with-internal-construc/5498261#5498261), like so:

```
mock.Setup(x => x.OnEvent(new object(), 
           Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(NotificationEventArgs),
                               BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                               null,
                               null,
                               null))
           );
```

Comment: Not a bad idea. Let me see what I can cook up with that.

Comment: I don't think this approach will work. I'm currently working on an events wrapper implementation that will *attempt* to emulate raising notification events manually given a mock.

Comment: I don't understand. For your example, it will work like this: `mock.Setup(x => x.OnEvent(new object(), Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(NotificationEventArgs),
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
    null,
    null,
    null)));`

Comment: I've chosen to go with a different path. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595588/how-to-test-events-firing